# What is the best method of processing optional group in Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I'm trying to write a function that enforces capitalization on certain words, and adds "'s" to certain words if they are followed by " s". For example, it should take grace s and transform that to Grace's.

```
r"(\b)(grace)( (s|S))?\b": posessive_name,
```

{...}

```
def possessive_name(match: Match) -> str:
    result = match.group(2).title()
    result = result.replace(" ", "'")
    return result  # type: ignore
```

I'm correctly "titlizing" it but can't figure out how to reference the optional ( (s|S)) group so that the ( 's) can be added if it's needed, and I'd like to avoid adding an additional regex... Is this possible?

*edited names for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this.

```
import re

test_str = "This is grace s apple."

def fix_names(match):
    name, s = match.groups()
    name = name.title()
    if s:
        name = f"{name}'s"
    return name

p = re.compile(r"\b(grace)(\s[sS])?\b")
print(p.sub(fix_names, test_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = (
    'a grace s apple',
    'the apple is grace s',
    'take alice s and steve s',
)
for line in lines:
    result = re.sub(r'(\w+)\s+s($|\s)', lambda m: m.group(1).title()+"'s"+m.group(2), line, flags=re.I|re.S)
    print(result)
```

you'll get:

> a Grace's apple
>
> the apple is Grace's
>
> take Alice's and Steve's

Answer (score 0):

You could capture 1+ word characters in group 1 followed by matching a space and either s or S using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

In the replacement use the `.title()` on group 1 and add `'s`

```
(?<!\S)(\w+) [sS](?!\S)
```

*Explanation*

- `(?<!\S)` Left whitespace boundary
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars
- `[sS]`  Match a space and either `s` or `S`
- `(?!\S)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZqXrg/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aF4Nx0)

*Code example*

```
import re
test_str = "grace s"
regex = r"(?<!\S)(\w+) [sS](?!\S)"
result = re.sub(regex, lambda match: match.group(1).title()+"'s", test_str)
print(result)
```

*Output*

```
Grace's
```

---

If you want to match *grace* specifically, you could use use an optional group. If you want match more words, you could use an alternation `(?:grace|anotherword)`

```
(?<!\S)(grace)(?: ([sS]))?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i65VXK/1)

*Example code*

```
import re
test_str = "Her name is grace."
strings = [
    "grace s",
    "Her name is grace."
]
pattern = r"(?<!\S)(grace)(?: ([sS]))?\b"
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for s in strings:
    print(
        regex.sub(
            lambda m: "{}{}".format(m.group(1).title(), "'s" if m.group(2) else '')
            , s)
    )
```

*Output*

```
Grace's
Her name is Grace.
```

Comment: From the OP, adds "'s" to certain words if they are followed by " s". The function needs to be able to handle cases that also don't have <space>s

Comment: @nicholishen Hi there,  the question states `and adds "'s" to certain words if they are followed by " s"` so I think there should be a space. In the pattern of the OP there is also a space. Note that `\s` matches a whitespace char, and could also match a newline which is different from a space.

Comment: You need to add the following test. "Her name is grace." It should have an 's appended.

Comment: If it is for grace specifically, I have added another option.

Comment: You could simplify the lambda a bit... `lambda m: "{}{}".format(m.group(1).title(), "'s" if m.group(2) else '')`